# Superposition and density matrix. What are these states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, superposition, density-operator

I just wanted to understand the following. Let's stay with the harmonic oscillator in QM, just to have an example at hand. 
First, there are all the different states for $n=1,2,...$. (Let's call them $\psi_n$).

Then, the superposition of a state, for example $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_1+ \psi_2)$$ is also a solution to the Schrödinqer equation.

But then, there is also the concept of a [density matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix), for example

$$\rho= \frac{1}{2} |\psi_1 \rangle \langle \psi_1| + \frac{1}{2} |\psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_2|.$$

My question is: What is the meaning of the concept of superposition and this density matrix state?

What I know so far is somewhat vague:I would say I can only measure whether a particle is in one of the $\psi_i$. The density matrix tells me that the particle is equally likely in one of the two states written down there, but if I would measure, then I would get one of them. But I don't really know what the superposition tells me? Which experimental setting corresponds to a superposition and what is the meaning of it?

If anything is unclear about my question, please let me know.

Comment: The superposition $1/\sqrt{2} (\psi_1 + \psi_2)$ is not equivalent to $\rho= \frac{1}{2} |\psi_1 \rangle \langle \psi_1| + \frac{1}{2} |\psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_2|$. Density operator corresponding to $\psi = 1/\sqrt{2} (\psi_1 + \psi_2)$ is $\rho_\psi = |\psi \rangle \langle \psi |$ which can be expanded into $\frac{1}{2}(|\psi_1\rangle \langle\psi_1| + |\psi_1\rangle \langle\psi_2| + |\psi_2\rangle  \langle\psi_1| + |\psi_2\rangle \langle\psi_2|)$

Comment: try to understand the example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Example:_Light_polarization which clarifies the distinction between pure states with a superposition and mixed states. Does that answer your question?

Comment: i read it, but the problem is that I can never see a harmonic oscillator in this superposition state, right? but why is this so and how is such a superposition state generated?

Comment: i understood that mixed states come from having a percentage of state one and of state 2, but a superposition? how do you create a superposition in a harmonic oscillator?

Comment: that's exactly the idea: you CAN see a Quantum harmonic oscillator in such a superposition state - for example, a coherent state (eigenstate of the annihilation operator) is a superposition of energy eigenstates. Preparation: e.g. photonic states. However, you COULDN'T see a classical harmonic oscillator in a superposition state - here, you can just have a mixed state (owing to the fact that you don't have enough knowledge about which state the system is in).

Comment: I can't believe this, sorry. I mean, why don't we observe in an hydrogen atom a line that is given by superposition of let's say the first orbital $n=1,l=0$ and the second one$n=2,l=0,$? this one should have some energy value between them(actually, it should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(E_1+E_2)$, which is less than the value of second one, but more than the energy of the first state). so, somehow superpositions cannot be actual states or where am I wrong?

Comment: The electron in hydrogen atom can be at a superposition of energy eigenstates, e.g. $|100 \rangle + |200 \rangle$. What we observed depends on how you measure the hydrogen atom. If you measure energy, the state vector collapses into an eigenstate of Hamiltonian. If you measure other quantity, the state vector collaspes into the eigenstate of the corresponding operator.

Comment: okay, so we can only MEASURE eigenstates, but I still not see the following: The electron is now in the state $|100\rangle$. So how do we get it back (for example by an experiment) in this state $|100\rangle + |200\rangle$?  I still do not see how do you end up with such a superposition state? The only principal way to do this would be(afais): Watch out for quantity that has this superposition state as an eigenstate and measure this one, but this is only a very theoretical way to do it. (We don't know whether we can find such a quantity)

Comment: (i) You can measure any state. Eigenstate for the given operator is the state after the measurement. E.g. $| \psi \rangle \rightarrow |n\rangle$. (ii) I don't know any practical method to prepare $| 100 \rangle + |200 \rangle$ from $| 100 \rangle$, maybe certain approach in quantum computing. Nevertheless, there is an easy way to obtain a superposition of energy eigenstates. In principle, you *watch* the electron (measure the position), the state collapse into position eigenstate. It is a superposition of energy eigenstates: $| x \rangle = \sum_n c_n |E_n \rangle$.